# Pulling a single facebook comment by id fails OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There seems to be something wrong with the facebook graph api right now. Even using API explorer tool generates the error. Can anyone pass a regular request for a single comment without throwing this exception?

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/|comment-id|

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code you have tried and the error text so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi @YakovL, thanks for your reply. There is no code really for the example I've given, simply using the Facebook Graph API explorer to debug.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Based on the documentation you can pass across a comment ID to pull back that specific comment. Presently it's not working, it was working two days ago and before that.

Error:   "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: EP6mAu0Bppc",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "DpWBACUo4yG"

You can pull a list but not one

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem for close to 24 hours now. I could not read a comment by the Facebook API anymore. It has been working prior to this.

Pulling comment - https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[comment-id]?access_token=[access-token]

Comment: I knew I wasn't alone. I've submitted a bug to facebook but they don't seem to understand my issue. It's very simple, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Actually it's not only pulling the comment but all related to the comment-id - I cannot get the list of likes for the comment and the list of comments for that comment.